# I can't run npm start to learn react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, babeljs

After installing it I used the npm install command and it generated this error.

```
 Module build failed: Error: Couldn't find preset "react" relative to directory "/ReduxSimpleStarter/src"
```

[Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmK2f.png)

from this repo https://github.com/StephenGrider/ReduxSimpleStarter

Comment: Did you do `npm install` before executing `npm start`?

Comment: This repo is 4 years old. I'd recommend spinning up a new app with [create-react-app](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/). You can even create one preinstalled with a Redux template using the [Redux Toolkit](https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started).

Comment: yes, i did! npm install. I also deleted the package-lock.json and the node_modules folder and installed it again. still it didn't work

Comment: yeah, but this is from a udemy's ethereum course =( ohh boy